# Issue with substitution

Tags: sage

I have a list L =  [a13 == a10, a14 == a11, a15 == a12, a16 == a7, a17 == a8, a18 == a9]

I then have a running through a loop giving it these values

a = 1

a = 2*a15*a16  + 2*a13*a17 + 2*a13*a18 +1849

etc

I have

print(a)

a.subs(L)

print(a)

and it indicates no change, but I would of thought/ expected substitution to of taken place. Maybe I am being idiot, but please tell me where.

Thanks.

Edit: Example code

I will write out some of my code + outputs:

> print L
>
> while k <= i[0].degree(t):
>
> ```
> a = i[0].coefficient({t:k})
> print a
> b = a.subs(L)
> print b
> ```

Don't understand why there is an extra box, but hopefully this makes sense.

An example of Outputs:

[a13 == a10, a13 ==  a11, a15 == a12, a16 == a7, a17 == a8, a18 == a9]

1

1

1

1

2*a15*16 + 2*a14*a17+2*a13*a13 + 1849

2*a15*16 + 2*a14*a17+2*a13*a13 + 1849

Hope this helps

Comment: Please review this for best results using this site.  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Cross-posted at https://ask.sagemath.org/question/36748/issues-with-substitution/

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are missing is that `a.subs(input)` is not intended to modify `a` - presumably so that one may do it many times.  Why not try this:

```
b = a.subs(L)
print b
```

Comment: Thanks, I just modified it to a = a.subs(L). But still had no luck. From a rudimentary check doing



a = var('a')


b = var('b')


L = a+b


L.substitute(a == 5) 


print L


This does the substitution for L.



Edit: I ran this and I take it back - I ran it and got different results from what I expected. In my example s.subs you are right does not change s.

Comment: I will write out some of my code + outputs:


print L
while k <= i[0].degree(t):
    a = i[0].coefficient({t:k})